# The set $C=\{(x,y):x>0,y<0\}$ is open

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Let there be $(x_{0},y_{0})\in C$ we need to find $r>0$ such that $B((x_{0},y_{0}),r)\subset C$.

lets take $r=\frac{min(|x_{0}|,|y_{0}|)}{2}$

$$|x-x_{0}|\leq \sqrt{(x-x_{0})^2+(y-y_{0})^2}<r=\frac{|x_{0}|}{2}$$

$$|x-x_{0}|<\frac{|x_{0}|}{2}$$

$$-\frac{|x_{0}|}{2}<x-x_{0}<\frac{|x_{0}|}{2}$$

$$0<x<\frac{3|x_{0}|}{2}$$

$$|y-y_{0}|\leq \sqrt{(x-x_{0})^2+(y-y_{0})^2}<r=\frac{|y_{0}|}{2}$$

$$|y-y_{0}|<\frac{|y_{0}|}{2}$$

$$-\frac{|y_{0}|}{2}<y-y_{0}<\frac{|y_{0}|}{2}$$

$(y_{0}<0)$

$$-3\frac{|y_{0}|}{2}<y<-\frac{|y_{0}|}{2}$$

So we have shown that for all x and y $(x,y)\in B((x_{0},y_{0}),r)\subset C$

1. the proof valid? or should there be just $(x,y)$?
2. can I say that (0,0) is a limit point that in not in $C$ and therefore it is open?

Comment: $0\not \in (0,1]$ but $(0,1]$ is not open.

Comment: So the countrey of the theorem that a set is closed iff all the limit points are in the set is not true

Comment: Not closed doesn't  implie open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof is valid. Just few small mistakes. $r\neq |x_0|/2$ but $r<|x_0|/2=x_0/2$ (you can drop the absolute value here). Similarly, $r<|y_0|/2$. For (2), you have to show that $(0,0)$ is a limit point and it is not in $C$. But this only proves that $C$ is not closed. As Abdullah mentioned, not closed does not mean it is open.